# Use VS2010 Setup Project to install VB6 application

Tags: visual-studio-2010, visual-studio, vb6, installation

Is it even possible to use VS2010 Setup Project to install Visual Basic 6 application, so that it detects and includes all its dependencies and other stuff automatically? I don't have the luxury of converting the entire code to .NET (it's a whole lot of stuff). Package & Deployment Wizard that ships with VB6 is proving to be a pain.

Alternately, can I use InstallShiled to achieve the same?

Comment: If you have your Visual Studio 6 disks, I beleive there is a limited edition InstallSheild that is an option when you install VS. I have used it in the Past. for vb6 I currently use the Visual Studio Installer add on that was available for Visual Interdev

Comment: @MarkHall: Thanks Mark. I was able to locate InstallShield on the original VS6 disk (though it is titled InstallShield for VC++ 6.0). It does install and accepts my executable. But after that, it leaves you free to add whatever components, dependencies, registry or whatever you want to add to the setup. You need to do all of it manually. This is unlike the VB6 Packaging Wizard that actually cruises through my exe and detects all dependencies. VS2010 Setup Project also has this feature. Any ideas?

Comment: Not really, the one that I use, it is hard to find the download anymore it is Visual Studio Installer and is a add on to Visual Interdev. The link is available in this [vbforums page](http://www.vbforums.com/showthread.php?592427-RESOLVED-Visual-Studio-Installer-1.1-Download-source)

Comment: VSI isn't really an add-on to Visual InterDev, but the VS IDE (DEVENV.EXE) does come up with that title on its splash screen.  More of a minor bug than anything else.  It has a simple VB6 Wizard in it, but for "real" packaging you need to create a blank project and use it much as you would any later VS IDE.

Comment: Also note that the VB6 Wizard in VS 6.0 Installer 1.1 will scan your .VBP and select/include the proper merge modules for dependencies if you set up the merge modules path.  You can use that if you're clueless, but it assumes you've actually downloaded and emplaced the VB6 merge modules (which do not ship in VB6 or in VSI 1.1), and set up the merge modules path in the Build Properties.

Answer (score 0):

The P&D wizard is dreadful.

WiX is probably the best solution for making VB6 installers - after I submitted some patches to compensate for some of the horrors that lurk within.